# Is it possible to have two sources of audio output to different speakers in android mobile?

Tags: android, audio, mobile, audio-streaming

I want to play a youtube video which should use bluetooth connected speaker as audio output. Same time I want to talk over phone which should use mobile's default speaker.
Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, you just need to write the code.